# Web Audio Api working with Decibels

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I wish to understand how to work with decibels in Web Audio API

Here i have an audio buffer connected to a gain node

```
var mybuffer = context.createBufferSource());
mybuffer.buffer = buffer; //an audio buffer

var gainNode=context.createGain();

mybuffer.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(context.destination);
```

Gain volume is a range from 0(silent) to n where 1 is the default volume but as i know, usually audio is not related to such a range, its volume is measured in decibels (Db) and operations are made in Db too.

I have read something interesting in this answer but it's far to be complete for my needs:
[Is there a way get something like decibel levels from an audio file and transform that information into a json array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734710/is-there-a-way-get-something-like-decibel-levels-from-an-audio-file-and-transfor)

I wonder how to determine decibel for an Audio Node, how to edit volume using decibels

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Decibels are an interesting beast.  Decibels aren't really a measure of volume, per se - they're a measure of gain or attentuation, as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel.  The number of decibels is ten times the logarithm to base 10 of the ratio of the two power quantities.

You *can* get decibels out of one critical place in the Web Audio API - the RealtimeAnalyser's  getFloatFrequencyData returns a float array of attenuation per frequency band, in decibels.  It's not technically volume - but it's attenuation from unity (1), which would be a sine wave in that frequency at full volume (-1 to 1).

Gain controls are, of course, commonly expressed in decibels, because they're a measure of a ratio - between unity and whatever your volume knob is set to.  Think of unity (0 dB, gain=1) as "as loud as your speakers will go".

To express a gain in decibels, remember that a gain of 1 (no attenuation, no gain) would equal 0 decibels - because 10^0 = 1.  (Actually - it's because 10 ^ (0/10) = 1.  Obviously, zero divided by anything is still zero - but remember, these are DECI-bels, there's a factor of ten in there.)  The aforementioned Wikipedia article explains this in good depth.

To convert between the two - e.g., to set a gain.value when you have decibels, and to get the decibel gain from gain.value - you just need to use the formula

```
decibel_level = 20 * log10( gain.value );
```

aka

```
gain.value = Math.pow(10, (decibel_level / 20));
```

Note that base 10 log is a little more complex in Javascript, due to only having access to the natural logarithm, not the base 10 logarithm - but you can get that via

```
function log10(x) {
    return Math.log(x)/Math.LN10;
}
```

(There's a Math.log10() method, but it's experimental and not implemented across all browsers.)

Comment: Actually, I think it should be `Math.pow(10, dB / 20)` (cf. http://teropa.info/blog/2016/08/30/amplitude-and-loudness.html)

Comment: I don't get it, so which code is right ? gain.value = Math.pow(10, (decibel_level / 20)); or Math.pow(10, dB / 20) ?

Comment: Regarding the comment above. Both formulas are ok, but they are the same. The previous comment seems to be erroneous.