# Setting volume level in dB in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I set the volume level in dB using this function?
Can I also control laterality (R/L volumes)?

```
function playNote1(frequency, duration) {
    // create Oscillator node
    var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

    oscillator.type = 'square';
    oscillator.frequency.value = frequency; // value in hertz
    oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    oscillator.start();
    setTimeout(function(){oscillator.stop();}, duration);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using gain node?

[GainNode docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode)

To calculate dB from linear multiplier for gainNode.gain use the formula:

20 * log(gainInDb)

Comment: Thanks. But do do I control the linear multiplier in my example? The GainNode docs seems a lot more complicated then this.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong, from my reading I think that formula calculates dB given a gain ratio, so you can't use that for `gainNode.gain`, instead I believe you want `gain.value = Math.pow(10, (decibel_level / 20));`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604500/web-audio-api-working-with-decibels/22613964#22613964