# How to replace createScriptProcessor with AudioWorklet using JavaScript for Chrome

Tags: javascript, webapi

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734710/is-there-a-way-get-something-like-decibel-levels-from-an-audio-file-and-transfor?newreg=94ff6a2b2e3d4f44854535d1a36b1267) and I know it is a little old but it seems like it should work however I am trying with Chrome 80 and I think the support for createScriptProcessor has ended as I can't get this to work as it is. I'm getting nothing for the input stream. From what I've read, the createScriptProcessor should be replaced with AudioWorklet however it doesn't look like a drop in solution. I am a beginner JS programmer and was wondering if someone has altered this to use the AudioWorklet function instead of the createScriptProcessor? Thanks,