# Get volume of audio file in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, volume, measure

Is it possible to get the max volume of a sound file via javascript without playing it? i dont mind in which form.

Comment: [This may help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode), and there's also [this answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735171/1377002).